# node reference fail before submit

Tags: 7, nodes

I have custom_form, with `node_reference_field`.. When I add Any node and leave some require field then I submit .. the `node_reference_field` fail and become [nid:und]

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $forms = array('register_node_form', 'session_node_form');
  if (in_array($form_id, $forms)) {
    if (empty($form['field_event_ref']['und'][0]['nid']['#default_value'])) {
      $form['field_event_ref']['und'][0]['nid']['#default_value'] = arg(3);
    }
    $form['field_event_ref']['und'][0]['nid']['#disabled'] = True;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($form_id == 'register_node_form'){
    global $user;
    if(isset($form_state['build_info']['args'][0]->field_event_ref[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'])){
       $nid = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0]->field_event_ref[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'];
    }  else {
    $nid = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0]->field_event_ref[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'] = arg(3);
    }
     $form_state['build_info']['args'][0]->field_event_ref[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'] = $nid;
```